# primefaces ui is not rendering properly

Tags: user-interface, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm having a problem with primefaces ui. It doesnt render icon that it was supposed to be rendered when I use  and the problem is not happening only on this but also on many other pages. I haven't used jquery.

I dont know what's wrong. Googled it but didnt find an answer.

Here is my code

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            template="/WEB-INF/faces/template.xhtml"
            xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
            xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:prettyfaces="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces">
<ui:param name="title" value="List of Employee"/>
<ui:define name="breadcrum1">
    <li><h:link value="Employee Management" outcome="pretty:home"/></li>
    <li><h:link value="List Employee Record" outcome="pretty:list_employee"/></li>
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10 span3">


                <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" globalOnly="true" style="text-align: center;"/>
                <h:form id="form">
                    <p:dataTable 
                        class="panel-primary table table-condensed"
                        var="employee" value="#{dtLazyView.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                        emptyMessage="No Employee found with given criteria"
                        paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single" selection="#{dtLazyView.selectedEmployee}" widgetVar="employeeTable" lazy="true">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Employee Information
                            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('employeeTable').filter()" style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column headerText="Id">
                            <h:outputText value="#{employee.employeeCode}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Employee Name">
                            <h:outputText value="#{employee.employeeName}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Employee Mobile Number">
                            <h:outputText value="#{employee.contact.mobileNumber}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Employee Role" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{employee.detail.employeeRole}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Option">
                            <h:commandButton action="#{employeeEditController.loadData(employee)}" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 40px;"> <f:ajax execute="@form"/></h:commandButton>

                            <p:commandButton update=":form:employeeDetail" oncomplete="PF('employeeDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search"  title="View">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{employee}" target="#{dtLazyView.selectedEmployee}" />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>

                    <p:dialog header="Employee Info" widgetVar="employeeDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" styleClass="">
                        <p:outputPanel id="employeeDetail" style="text-align:center;">
                            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty dtLazyView.selectedEmployee}" columnClasses="label,value">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <img src="../../imageshandler/#{dtLazyView.selectedEmployee.employeePicture}" class="img-responsive" style="width:200px;height: 200px;margin-left: 100px;border-radius: 50%"/>
                                </f:facet>

                                <h:outputText value="Name :" style="color: black"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{dtLazyView.selectedEmployee.employeeName}" />

                                <h:outputText value="DOB :" style="color: black"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{dtLazyView.selectedEmployee.employeeDob}" />

                                <h:outputText value="Gender :" style="color: black"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{dtLazyView.selectedEmployee.sex}" style="color:#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.color}"/>

                                <h:outputText value="Salary : " style="color: black" />
                                <h:outputText value="Rs : #{dtLazyView.selectedEmployee.salary.basicSalary}" />

                                <h:outputText value="Working date :" style="color: black"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{dtLazyView.selectedEmployee.employeeDateOfCommencement}"/>

                                <h:outputText value="Employee Job Specification :" style="color: black"/>
                                <h:inputTextarea value="#{dtLazyView.selectedEmployee.detail.jobSpecification}" readonly="true"/>



                            </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:dialog>


                </h:form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:define>
```

[image: Doesnot render previous and forward]

Comment: try addind an empty `<h:head>` tag and see if it works

Comment: Can you post code of your css classes? They may override default primeface's css properties for icons. Also you can check compiled css style for elements in your browser. Just launch debugger (press F12 in firefox or chrome) and inspect interested element by click on it.

Comment: @Apostolos i have use <h:head> in my template.xhtml file for custom ecomponent rendering

Comment: you should see in html source the `theme.css`. this is where all these icons are referenced.

Comment: but there is only theme.css.xhtml file and it only show line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml), you can use *Font Awesome* for the icons, so try replacing

```
icon="ui-icon-search"
```

with

```
icon="fa fa-search"
```

Keep in mind

> Font Awesome icons are provided out of the box within PrimeFaces. In
>   order to enable Font Awesome support, enable primefaces.FONT_AWESOME
>   setting as true via a context param.

Comment: but the code he posted is copy-pasted code from the official showcase so it should work even like this.

Comment: yeah, I have used same code of primeface datatable and still not rendering

Comment: @Apostolos any better ideas??

Comment: @esteban rincon yeah it worked for me but how do i represent previous and next icon from datatable sir??